# How to have the dollar sign printed in a multi-line variable with GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using the sample Makefile below to print the  SCRIPT_BODY depending on the VAR value:

```
define SCRIPT_BODY
begin
    foo=$(VAR)
end
endef
export SCRIPT_BODY

.PHONY: all
all:
        $(MAKE) body VAR='$$bar'

.PHONY: body
body:
        @echo "$$SCRIPT_BODY"
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following output

```
begin
    foo=ar
end
```

instead of

```
begin
    foo=$bar
end
```

Any ideas on how to have the dollar sign printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with the fact the `SCRIPT_BODY` is a multi-line variable: you get the same result with `SCRIPT_BODY=foo=$(VAR)`. In fact `$$bar` gets evaluated twice by `make`: once when assigning `VAR` and once when assigning `SCRIPT_BODY` before exporting it to the shell. The first evaluation leads to `$bar`, thus the second to `ar`, as `b` is not a variable of your `Makefile`. You can prevent this second evaluation by using the [value](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Value-Function.html#Value-Function) function of make:

```
define SCRIPT_BODY
begin
    foo=$(value VAR)
end
endef
```

Comment: Using the "value" function solved the issue. Thanks, Virgile!